# Is there a way to loop through all jwplayer instances when the number is unknown?

Tags: javascript, loops, jwplayer

Seemingly simple question, but I haven't seen anything in the jwplayer javascript API that leads me to an answer.

I'm trying to loop through all instances of jwplayer objects on my page without keeping track of the number that may be on the page.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

The solution I'm using for now is:

```
var maxPlayers = 20;
for(var i = 0; i < maxPlayers; i++) {           
    if(jwplayer(i)) {
        // execute code on jwplayer instance here
    }       
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: Yes, but I was waiting to hear back from @SLaks before deciding which one worked best for me.  I'd like to not have to keep track of the instances as that can get complicated when working around bugs in IE (removing dom elements and reinstantiating the player in order to stop audio from playing after a dom element has has it's display set to none).

Comment: You mean you don't stop the audio first before setting the display to none? Though, wrapping the `stop` event call inside a try catch is still advised in all cases anyway :)

Comment: I will try that the next time I come up against this issue.  Was running into all sorts of problems with any IE (v7-9) throwing "Undefined error" coming from the jwplayer.js when calling any method of the jwplayer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could keep looping until `jwPlayer` returns null:

```
var i = 0;
while (true) {
    var player = jwPlayer(i);
    if (!player)
        break;

    ...
    i++;
}
```

Or, more tersely,

```
var i = 0;
while (player = jwPlayer(i++)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but is i coming from the loop?  If so, I'm not sure how this gets around the prob of setting an upper limit to search up to.

Comment: @evanmcd he probably meant to initialize `i = 0` before the loop and `++i` at the end of the loop

Comment: @evanmcd: Jack is correct;  I forgot that.  Sorry; SO didn't notify me about your comment for some reason.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now.  I like the way this keeps from having to track instances.  Thanks.

Comment: i need to check `if (player.id)` in jwplayer 6.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of them when they're inserted, like so:

```
var players = [];
function playerReady(obj) {
    players.push(document.getElementById(obj.id));
};
```

Then, to do stuff:

```
for (var player in players) {
    players[player].sendEvent("STOP");
}
```

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu i guess? :)